# IE8 CSS rotation works locally, but not uploaded to server

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, rotation

so i'm using this beast for IE8 rotation:

```
.no-csstransforms {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.34202014, M12=0.93969262, M21=-0.93969262, M22=0.34202014,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
}
```

works like a charm locally. But as soon as i upload it to the server, it breaks. It's just a flat line there. Tested on IE9 and IE10 in "IE 8 Mode".

So far, the only difference between local and remote was this rotation. According to IE dev tools, the CSS is applied.

My question is: why is IE8 showing different CSS behaviour for local and remote files and how can i get persistent results across both?

**UPDATE**:
I may have confused some of you about the X-UA meta tag. I included it only because i read on stackoverflow that not-incuding it would cause inconsistencies offline and online in IE8.

I really don't get IE8.

This example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css"> 
    .me {
        border-bottom: 1px solid red;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .csstransforms .me {        
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-70deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-70deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-70deg);
        transform: rotate(-70deg);
    }

    .no-csstransforms .me {
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.34202014, M12=0.93969262, M21=-0.93969262, M22=0.34202014,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
</head>



<body>
    <div class="me"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

doesn't work locally for me.
In my actual usecase, it is working locally but not uploaded to a server.
The fiddle is here
http://jsfiddle.net/SPMxZ/1/

Comment: *Tested on IE9 and IE10 in "IE 8 Mode"* -- don't do this; you won't get an accurate copy of a real IE8, particularly for stuff like this. You really *really* should be testing using a real copy of IE8.

Comment: not yet. Still trying and researching but i'll update here if i do.

Comment: just to update: i got a dinosaur of laptop with Windows XP and native IE8. Everything works like a charm on there so i guess the "IE8 Mode" of IE10 is to blame here.

Answer (score 0):

While using

```
<meta http-equiv="...
```

you ask the browser to add some content to the request header ([msdn http-equiv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Maybe I get the "locally" in your question wrong - but if you don't use a local server - all you do is opening a file in the browser which is no request - so nothing is added to the response header - hence your

```
<meta http-equiv="...
```

is not evaluated. 
The IE version stays "IE8 Mode". ("locally")

Delivered from the server the response header is now carrying your compatibility override to "edge" and so your IE10 which you set to IE8 Mode [is getting "edge"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is IE10 in your case.

So as @Spudley said to test on IE8 - don't use a IE10 because with your http-equiv compatibility rule you switch the render mode you just set manually.

To spot this issues easier:

- use a local server stack (e.g. [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html))
- use use native Browsers in a Virtual Machine ( e.g. [modern IE](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools))

If this did not help, it would be cool if you could provide a **jsfiddle**, because anything that is beyond the mentioned be it missing layout on the styled element could spoil your css

Comment: wait, no. I included the meta tag only because i read that this would be solving IE8 differences locally and on a server.
yes, i'm just opening a local HTML file with lots of JS and CSS included in the browser. No server side language in play here.
If i remove the meta tag the behavious is the same. IE9+ has different CSS anyway. It's just about IE8 and the difference in rotation locally and uploaded to a server.

Please see me edited question for an example